# Establecer valor select en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: php, formularios

Estoy programando una calculadora simple donde el usuario selecciona la operación que desea realizar a través de un `select`:

```
    <select name="select" value= <?php echo isset($_SESSION['operacion']) && !empty($_SESSION['operacion']) ? $_SESSION['operacion'] : "sumar"  ?>>
        <option value="sumar">Sumar</option>
        <option value="restar">Restar</option>
        <option value="multiplicar">Multiplicar</option>
        <option value="dividir">Division</option>
    </select>
```

pero no consigo establecer el valor del `select` con la última opción que seleccionó el usuario, la sesión contiene el `value` del `option` osea `"sumar","restar" ...` y el valor es correcto ya que lo he comprobado.

Código para guardar el valor;

```
                $operacion=$_REQUEST["select"];
                $_SESSION["operacion"] = $operacion;
```

Una de las condiciones del ejercicio es que hay que realizarlo empleando únicamente `php`, no se permite el uso de `javaScript`.

Comment: La etiqueta select no debe llevar value, debe recoger el de la opción seleccionada. Para marcar una opción debes poner en dicha opción el atributo selected.

Comment: @Carmen el problema es que yo no sabré cual tengo que marcar hasta que el usuario realice un primer cálculo y guarde en la sesión el valor.

Comment: Te pongo un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para seleccionar una opción se pone el atributo selected en la opción correspondiente.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['operacion']) && !empty($_SESSION['operacion'])) {
  $opcionxdefecto = $_SESSION['operacion'];
} else {
  $opcionxdefecto = "sumar";
}
?>

<select name="select">
        <option value="sumar" <?php if ($opcionxdefecto=="sumar") { echo "selected";}?>>Sumar</option>
        <option value="restar" <?php if ($opcionxdefecto=="restar") { echo "selected";}?>>Restar</option>
        <option value="multiplicar" <?php if ($opcionxdefecto=="multiplicar") { echo "selected";}?>>Multiplicar</option>
        <option value="dividir" <?php if ($opcionxdefecto=="dividir") { echo "selected";}?>>Division</option>
    </select>
```

Cuando el usuario seleccione la operación recoges el valor del select en el formulario y actualizas la variable de sesión en la que guardas la operación.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
//Establecemos la lista de operaciones disponibles
$operaciones = array("sumar","restar","multiplicar","dividir");
// Comprobamos si ya ha realizado una selección anteriormente
$anterior = (!empty($_SESSION['operacion'])) ? false : $_SESSION['operacion'];
foreach ($operaciones as $op) {
    // Verificamos si esta operación es igual que la de la sesion y de ser así establecemos el selected de HTML
    $selected = (strtolower(trim($op))==strtolower(trim($anterior))) ? ' selected="true" ' : '';

    // Imprimimos el option con sus valores y adicionalmente agregamos o no el atributo selected.
    echo '<option value="'.strtolower($op).'" '.$selected.'>'.ucfirst($op).'</option>';
}


?>
```